# How to set fancyhdr subsection to first subsection name on page?

Tags: fancyhdr

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\let\Sectionmark\sectionmark
\def\sectionmark#1{\def\Sectionname{#1}\Sectionmark{#1}}
\let\Subsectionmark\subsectionmark
\def\subsectionmark#1{\def\Subsectionname{#1}\Subsectionmark{#1}}

\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[R]{ \sffamily \quad \nouppercase { 
    \thesubsection\ \Sectionname\quad$>$\quad\Subsectionname} 
}


\begin{document}

\section{Section A}
Null vier drei neun sieben.

\subsection{Subsection a}
Zwölf sieben neun eins drei.


\subsection{Subsection b}
Acht elf elf fünf drei vier.


\end{document}
```

Which produces
[image: Output of the MWE.]

What I would like to have though, is that the first subsection on every page is set into the header, not the last one. To be more precise: The problem is, that allways the last subsection of the section is put into the header, even if that subsection starts 10 pages below the section.

Inserting a `\newpage` between the subsections leads to the desired behavoir, but I would like to avoid a page break after every`\subsection`.

Comment: Why do you want that behavior? If you want to search for a subsection and only look at the header, the default behavior (show the last subsection of a page) is more useful.

Comment: I just edited the question since I believe there was a misunderstanding: What you're saying makes sense, but the problem with above MWE is, that allways the very last subsection of a section is displayed in the header, even if there are a few pages beetween that last subsection and the section beginning.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. But if I take your MWE and insert a `\newpage` before subsection b, it shows the desired behavior, i.e. first page: "1.1 Section A > Subsection a" and second page: "1.2 Section A > Subsection b".

Comment: While I can confirm this, I would like to avoid the `\newpage` at the end of every `\subsection`. Is there a macro that could force the headers to behave like `\newpage` without generating a page break? Or is it generally considered good practice in typesetting to do a page break after every subsection indeed?

Comment: I made the example with `\newpage` just to show that *not* "always the very last subsection of a section is displayed", as you said in your problem description. So it's not generally good practice to put a `\newpage` before every subsection. Maybe you can edit and extend your question to make it more clear.